# Call Readonly function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, readonly

I'm building an app with an immutable data model and I reached the following dead-end:

I have a function that is stored as immutable like in the following example:

```js
const f: Readonly<() => void> = () => {};
f();
```

When calling `f` I get the following error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'Readonly<() => void>' has no call signatures. (2349)
```

I fail to understand what is transformed by Readonly that produces this effect.

Casting back to mutable doesn't seem to be a solution. This produces the same error:

```js
export type Mutable<T> = {
    -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};

(f as Mutable<typeof f>)();
```

I'm looking to understand the root cause of this issue, not necessarily look for workarounds, like casting to the exact function type, or not applying Readonly to functions.

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgLhgJQKYEMAm4A2BPAHgAoBKGAXgD4YA3EAS02vJlIuoG8BfAbgCg4pfnz6oAHgAcQAJ1hQ8E1DACyAVyjoARjlQEAKsxgc+MUzAC00jNjD4YAbQDSMemBgBrVHhBwYegLpIek7+-LwiRL7oECrqWjoE8oo+8JQkQnyRMNGsZFS0DJjpJMLiUrIwSUoAwqrQIAC2aFi4hAYUfjDiUKhgmDFs+ehgeDAA-J1IxmYwVi22o04ubp7evgFBIWH8oJCwAOZItfVN1q3EedR0jIaDnOH7GUA).

Comment: What is the intended purpose of making a function read-only? Are you trying to prevent its properties (e.g. `f.apply`) from being reassigned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Readonly<Function>` to say that the function's properties (e.g. `apply`, `bind`, `call`...) are read-only, and an intersection type to retain the function's call signature.

```js
type ReadonlyFunction<F extends Function> = Readonly<Function> & F;

const f: ReadonlyFunction<() => void> = () => {};

// OK
f();

// Error: Expected 0 arguments, but got 2.
f(1, 2);

// Error: Cannot assign to 'apply' as it is a readonly property.
f.apply = 'foo';
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCGATA9gOwDYgGIFdUGNgBLNAHiyggA9gJVEBnKXA4tAPigF5YEUMQ5PIRKpOAMmYBuAFAz8aBsCgAzAFy8kaTCxFkAFAEpunAG7IiiTjyMmoAbwC+smQHpXUAPIBpGSqMu7lAAogBOocihGsFUkIQQiFAADFDwoQDmOAC2dMAMADRQAEY4yunIygBMAHR++gCMhZWGgR5hEVFQAMLwqKgVqQwMROmoUMDIUADk8GBgmFODUETKREzwUKF82iBQYBGQoaC1KtWz87s8UyrIyFNSQA)

---

The reason why `Readonly<() => void>` doesn't work seems to be that `Readonly` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), so it maps the properties of the type `() => void`, but not the call signature.

It turns out that the type `() => void` has no properties, so e.g. `keyof (() => void)` is `never`, and `{ [K in keyof (() => void)]: any }` is `{}`.

Comment: yeah. I missed the fact that `{}` is assignable to `Readonly<() => void>` that's a pretty good reason to not allow me to call it. I guess what seems unintuitive to me is that `Readonly<number>` is a `number`, but `Readonly<() => void>` isn't a `() => void` even though `"number"` and `"function`" are both possible return values of `typeof`. although I guess `function` is not a primitive type. I can't say Readonly<function>